# How to do indirect variable evaluation

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print a simple value for `$AR1_p1` but the variable `$i` is not evaluating.

```bsh
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    AR1_p1=22
    AR1_p2=23
    AR1_p3=24
    AR1_p3=25
    echo $AR1_p$i
done
```

It's like concatenating dynamically. Any suggestions on how to fix this?.

Comment: Perhaps the echo line should be: echo $AR1_p1$i

Comment: @parkamark, I want this to be dynamic like p1,p2 etc.

Comment: You should use arrays instead. What you want is not possible (or at least very bad style).

Comment: @Sven, I understand i can use arrays but since i have only 4 values to evaluate. So this is a problem with bash ?.

Comment: @serverliving.com no, this is not a problem with Bash. Bash is behaving exactly the way it should, and this is indeed an issue for which it makes sense to use an array. Why is it an issue to use an array of 4 elements?

Comment: Just FYI, the reason your original idea didn't work is that your solution concatenates two variables, `$AR1_p` (which doesn't exist) and `$i`. An example for using this feature might be: `today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d); filename="backup-$today.tar.gz"`

Comment: Was setting `AR1_P3` twice in a row intentional, or should the the line before the echo be `AR1_P4=25` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This loop works. Else use Arrays.

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4; do AR1_p1=22; AR1_p2=23; AR1_p3=24; AR1_p4=25; echo $((AR1_p$i)); done 
22
23
24
25
```

Comment: Note this will only work for integer-valued parameters.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [bash indirect references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78) for that:

```bash
AR1_p1=22
AR1_p2=23
AR1_p3=24
AR1_p4=25
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  VARNAME="AR1_p${i}"
  echo "${!VARNAME}"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Per suggested comment(s), array should be used:

```
#!/bin/bash

AR1_p=(22 23 24 25)

for i in {1..4}
do
  echo "${AR1_p[$i-1]}"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The `for` loop is an array assignment already...

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't make any sense. As much as this has had up votes, it didn't fully address the true requirement of the original question. That was addressed in the other answer above relating to "bash indirect references" which is a better solution for what the OP was trying to achieve. My post does, however, demonstrates some of the intricacies that can be employed in BASH to achieve the same thing, noting that the above could simply be reduced to "for i in {22..25}; do echo $i; done", but that answer doesn't really have any relevance to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Use eval:

```
#!/bin/bash

AR1_p1=22
AR1_p2=23
AR1_p3=24
AR1_p4=24
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    eval echo \$AR1_p$i
done
```

echo expands only $i. When this expression reaches eval, it is like : $AR1_p1. Eval tries to evaluate and gives the result.

Comment: `eval` is usually a bad idea.  In this example of course you aren't handling external input, but if you ever do you need to be *very* sure you sanitize any data you pass to `eval`.  (Which is hard.  *Very* hard.  Better to just skip it.)

Comment: @Wildcard - it isn't all that hard, really. And learning how to do it the right way *shouldn't be skipped*.

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do  AR1_p1=22
    AR1_p2=23
    AR1_p3=24
    AR1_p4=25
    echo "$((AR1_p$i))"
done
```

A little less messy, maybe:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do  echo "$((AR1_p$i=i+21))"
done
```

Still POSIXly, but far more sensible:

```
i=0 n=21 l=4
while  [ "$l" -ge "$((i+=1))" ]
do     echo "$((AR1_p$i=i+n))"
done
```