# What is correct syntax to for loop variable in PATH?

Tags: path, for

I have to execute following loop:

```
root1=path/to/root1
root2=path/to/root2   
for i in {1..2}; do ${root${i}}; done
```

It **doesn't** give desired output:

```
path/to/root1
path/to/root2
```

Admin suggested thread brought solutions that doesn't lead to result i seek, e.g.

```
for i in {1..2}; do \$root$i; done
```

Output:

```
$root1
$root2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do indirect variable evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255854/how-to-do-indirect-variable-evaluation)

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Which shell are you using? (`bash`?)

Comment: Hey roaima, yes.

Comment: @muru, (and others), even though the code in the question hints at using indirect variables, perhaps it would be better to guide users to using arrays in cases where they fit.

Comment: @ilkkachu of course. There are bunch of dupe targets for variable indirection, so maybe let's pick a canonical one that suggests arrays first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `bash` shell, it looks as if you want to use an array:

```bash
root[1]=path/to/root1
root[2]=path/to/root2

for i in {1..2}; do
    printf '%s\n' "${root[i]}"
done
```

or, write the assignment to `root` as a single array assignment (note that the first index is 0 in a `bash` array unless explicit indices are used),

```bash
root=( path/to/root1 path/to/root2 )

for i in {0..1}; do
    printf '%s\n' "${root[i]}"
done
```

and/or, loop over the values of the array (not its indices),

```bash
root=( path/to/root1 path/to/root2 )

for i in "${root[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

(to just output the array, the loop is not needed, `printf '%s\n' "${root[@]}"` will be enough to print the values of the array on separate lines)

---

In general, you may not know what indices are used by the array (an array may have discontinuous indices), so to loop over the available indices, you would loop over `"${!root[@]}"`:

```bash
root=( path/to/root1 path/to/root2 )

for i in "${!root[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${root[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Firs suits well. Shorter version also gives desired output: for i in {1..2}; do ${root[i]}; done