# How can I substitute part of a variable using random inputs?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a small shell script, but am now stuck in a place where I have to create a directory based on the input that I get. Below is the scenario

I have 2 directories

```
DIR_PRE=/path/to/dir/dir_PRE

DIR_POST=/path/to/dir/dir_POST
```

Now, I want to use one function to create either directories based on the input sent to function i.e.

- if I send `create_dir PRE` it should create 1st directory and
- if I send `create_dir POST` it should create 2nd directory.

`create_dir` being the function defined below:

```bsh
create_dir ()
{
  STAGE=$1
  mkdir -p $DIR_${STAGE}  # <-- how to get this right?
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to do indirect variable evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255854/how-to-do-indirect-variable-evaluation) ex. (avoiding ALLCAPS variable names) `stage_dir=DIR_$1; mkdir "${!stage_dir}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One relatively easy method is to use an `if` construct:

```bsh
create_dir()
{
  if [[ $1 == "PRE" ]]
  then
      mkdir -p "$DIR_PRE"
  elif [[ $1 == "POST" ]]
  then
      mkdir -p "$DIR_POST"
  else
      echo "Illegal argument $1!"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee . I feel silly now knowing the answer and realizing how silly it was of me to have missed this workaround :D

Comment: @Manish don't worry, happens to all of us ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should try and avoid capitalized variable names. Those are not variables you want to export and should confuse you less. Here is a simple snippet you can run to get what you want

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir_pre="$HOME"/dir_PRE
dir_post="$HOME"/dir_POST

die(){ echo >&2 "$@"; exit 1; }

create_dir()
{
    local dir="$1"
    case $dir in
        PRE)    mkdir -p "$dir_pre";;
        POST)   mkdir -p "$dir_post";;
        *) die "option not known";;
    esac
}
create_dir "$@"
```